# Subset counting problem, creating a bijection

Tags: probability

The question is

> What is the probability that a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,12\}$ of size 6 contains the number 1?

The brute force method is to count how many subsets 1, which amounts to counting how many subsets of size 5 there are in $\{2,\dots,12\}$, i.e. $\binom{11}{5}$. Hence the answer is
$$\frac{\binom{11}{5}}{\binom{12}{6}} = \frac12.$$
But how could one see that there is an immediate bijection between subsets containing 1 and not containing 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bijection you want is just:  "map a subset to its complement".  Easy to see that, given a subset $S$ and its complement $\overline S$, then $1$ is in exactly one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

One insight is that selecting $6$ out of $12$ items gives probability one-half that the particular number $1$ falls in the selected subset (because selected and leftover subsets are equal in size).

Comment: does this mean that if the subsets were of size 4, there would be a $1/3$ chance of selecting 1?

Comment: Yes, that is a correct generalization.

Comment: ha! This is such a stupidly easy question I have no idea why I overcomplicated it